# How to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n-\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2-1}} \right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

This is an [admission question](http://server-test.net/math/php.php?name=tokyo&v1=1&v2=2001&v3=2&v4=1&y=2001&n=7) of Tokyo University：
For all natural number $n\geqslant2$, we always have

$$n-\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2-1}}\geqslant\cfrac{i}{10}$$
in which $i$ is integer, please calculate the maximum 0f $i$.

I have worked out this problem, furthermore, how to calculate

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n-\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2-1}}\right)$$
is the value a transcendental number？

Comment: I see no reason to think this number $0.6398101128040858$ can be written in closed form.

Comment: $=1-\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{I_1(x)\,dx}{e^x(e^x-1)}$.

Comment: @ GEdgar: Could you explain how to get the number 0.6398101128040858? I will be grateful.

Comment: [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) "eats" the integral easily: \begin{align*}&\texttt{> \p80}\\&\texttt{> 1-intnum(x=0,[oo,1],besseli(1,x)/exp(x)/(exp(x)-1))}\\&\texttt{%1 = 0.639810112804085832132255540293901469300884201}\color{red}{\cdots}\end{align*}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that
$$
\frac{k}{{\sqrt {k^2  - 1} }} = 1 + \frac{1}{{(k + \sqrt {k^2  - 1} )\sqrt {k^2  - 1} }}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {n - \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{k}{{\sqrt {k^2  - 1} }}} } \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {1 - \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{1}{{(k + \sqrt {k^2  - 1} )\sqrt {k^2  - 1} }}} } \right).
$$
Observe that our sequence is decreasing, so we indeed need to estimate this limit efficiently. Now
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{1}{{(k + \sqrt {k^2  - 1} )\sqrt {k^2  - 1} }}}  \le \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{1}{{k^2  - 1}}}  \to \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^2  - 1}}}  = \frac{3}{8}
$$
and
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{1}{{(k + \sqrt {k^2  - 1} )\sqrt {k^2  - 1} }}}  \ge \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{1}{{k^2 }}}  \to \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^2 }}}  = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6} - 1} \right) \ge 0.322.
$$
Consequently,
$$
0.625 \le \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {n - \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{k}{{\sqrt {k^2  - 1} }}} } \right) \le 0.678,
$$
and the answer is $i=6$.

Comment: Your solution is greater than mine.However, I wanna can we calculate the detailed specific value of limit？

Comment: I do not think there is a simple closed form for it. Consult metamorphy on how to get the representation involving the modified Bessel function. That integrad decays like $e^{-x}x^{-1/2}$ so you can expect fast convergence.